# Datediff with CASE and Group By

Tags: hive

I am trying to collapse a table into a single row per id, having trouble including a DATEDIFF function with the GROUP BY and CASE statements:

```
SELECT
o.id1
,o.id2
,count(case when o.type = 'TEST' and DATEDIFF(o.dte, m.dte) < 30 then id3 end) as win_30

FROM table1 m 
LEFT JOIN table2 0
ON (m.id = o.id2)
WHERE o.load_dt BETWEEN '20181001' AND '20181010'
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

I keep getting a '`Expression not in GROUP BY`' error when I run this code, and the problem seems to be with the `datediff` (when I take out 'and `DATEDIFF(o.dte, m.dte) < 30`' it runs just fine). Do I need the `datediff` in the `GROUP BY` somehow?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the exact query, table alias are t1 and t2, whereas in select clause and join condition you are referring o and m

Comment: Apologies, fixed now.

Comment: Why not to `group by o.id1 ,o.id2` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any error for similar query.

```
hive> select * from test_d1;
OK
1       2       10
3       4       20
5       6       30

hive> select * from test_d2;
OK
1       5
3       10
```

Query - `hive> select t1.id1, t1.id2, count(case when t2.id3=1 and nvl(t1.dte,t2.dte) < 10 then 1 else 0 end) as col3 from test_d1 t1 left outer join test_d2 t2 on t1.id1=t2.id3 group by 1,2;`

Output -

```
OK
1       2       1
3       4       1
5       6       1
```

Tried with position in group by instead of columns (you have to set set **hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias = true**)

```
hive> select t1.id1, t1.id2, count(case when t2.id3=1 and nvl(t1.dte,t2.dte) < 10 then 1 else 0 end) as col3 from test_d1 t1 left outer join test_d2 t2 on t1.id1=t2.id3 group by 1,2;
OK
1       2       1
3       4       1
5       6       1
```

One more observation - why do you want to go for left outer join when the columns in select list is from right side of the table